# Google apps script execute a function twice when it suppose to execute

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've built a bot to receive inputs from users, the inputs are mainly numbers and months and names of the user. The data received by the telegram bot will be stored in the google sheet via google apps script.

however, as the user base grew and the amount of data that is logged onto the sheet grew too. This caused a problem as I'm using a loop to delete incomplete entries from users. Ever since the introduction of this loop that deletes incomplete entries, I'm facing a weird problem where the doPost function is executed twice.

I've read a similar post and the solution to this problem seemed to be using the method `flush()`

Since I'm quite new, could you guys advise me where to insert the `flush()` method ?
Based on what I read I thought this would be where I should put my `flush()` method.

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([date, id, "Others"]);, will sometimes get executed twice or more if the runtime of the script is too long, which I think is due to the loop function.

Original code:

```
var token = "xxx"; 
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "yyy";
var theta = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Log");

function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var id = contents.message.from.id;

  if (contents.message.text == "Others") {
    sendText(id, "Can I get your rank and name, sir?", keyBoardName);
    var sheetlastrow = theta.getLastRow();
    // the for loop to delete any incomplete entries
    for (let o = sheetlastrow; o > 0; o--) {
      cellremarks = theta.getRange(o, 14).getValue();
      celluserid = theta.getRange(o, 2).getValue();
      if (cellremarks == "remarks" && celluserid == id) {
        numberOfRowsinbtw = sheetlastrow - o; // Returns number of rows between latest entry and latest completed entry of user
        for (let hoj = 1; hoj <= numberOfRowsinbtw; hoj++) {
          cellbelowlatest = o + hoj // gives the row number below latest completed entry of user
          queryuserid = theta.getRange(cellbelowlatest, 2).getValue();
          if (theta.getRange(cellbelowlatest, 2).getValue() == id) {
            theta.getRange("B" + cellbelowlatest + ":M" + cellbelowlatest).clearContent()
          }
        }
        break
      }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([date, id, "Others"]);
  }
}
```

My Attempt on inserting the `flush()` method:

```
if (contents.message.text == "Others") {
sendText(id,"Can I get your rank and name, sir?", keyBoardName );
var sheetlastrow = theta.getLastRow();
for (let o = sheetlastrow; o > 0; o--) {
  cellremarks = theta.getRange(o, 14).getValue();
  celluserid = theta.getRange(o, 2).getValue();
  if (cellremarks == "remarks" && celluserid == id) {
    numberOfRowsinbtw = sheetlastrow - o; // Returns number of rows between latest entry and latest completed entry of user
    for (let hoj = 1; hoj <= numberOfRowsinbtw; hoj++) {
      cellbelowlatest = o + hoj // gives the row number below latest completed entry of user
      queryuserid = theta.getRange(cellbelowlatest, 2).getValue();
      if (theta.getRange(cellbelowlatest, 2).getValue() == id) {
        theta.getRange("B" + cellbelowlatest + ":M" + cellbelowlatest).clearContent()
      }
    }
    break
  }
}
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([date,id,"Others"]);
}
```

Can you guys tell me if this is where I should insert my `.flush()` method?

Comment: It looks like you positioned `flush()` correctly. 1. But the loop can me much more efficient if you manage to grab all your date in one step (as a 2d array) and process it within a script instead of several `getValue()` calls to the server. See the best practices https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices 2. I'm not sure, but probably in this case it makes sense to try Lock Service: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock

Comment: wow thats good , didnt know that locking up the code could prevent the code from being used while its executing somefunction , ill take a look into that. right now the flush method doesnt seem to be giving me anyproblem, ill update here in a few weeks if flush is really the solution. thanks :D